# RestSharp C# HTTP POST Oauth 1

Tags: c#, api, http, restsharp

I am running into a difficulty with HTTP POST and Oauth 1, RestClient C#. I am able to make successful calls with HTTP GET and Oauth, but for some reason HTTP Post fails. I was able to make successful HTTP POST calls with same credentials using Postman, but not with RestSharp. Perhaps someone could help me figuring out the issue.

Here are the screenshots with working HTTP POST Oauth1 Postman call:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The Postman setup above works just fine, and here is what I have so far in C# and RestClient:

```
        public bool CreateShippingTemplate(string storeProviderStoreId, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string oAuthToken, string oAuthTokenSecret)
    {
        string url = "/shipping/templates";
        var request = GenerateSecureRequest(url, RequestType.POST, consumerKey, consumerSecret, oAuthToken, oAuthTokenSecret);

        var dataObj = new //ShippingTemplate
        {
            title = "Test Title 2",
            origin_country_id = "209",
            primary_cost = "1",
            secondary_cost = "1"
        };

        string dataObjJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataObj);

        request.AddParameter("application/json", dataObjJson, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        request.Method = Method.POST;
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var response = _restClient.ExecuteAsPost(request,"POST");

        return true;
    }



        private RestRequest GenerateSecureRequest(string url, RequestType requestType, string consumerKey, string consumerSecret, string oAuthToken, string oAuthTokenSecret)
    {
        OAuthBase oAuth = new OAuthBase();

        string nonce = oAuth.GenerateNonce();
        string timeStamp = oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp();
        string normalizedUrl;
        string normalizedRequestParameters;

        string relativeUri = url;
        string sig = oAuth.GenerateSignature(new Uri(BASE_URL.ToString() + relativeUri), consumerKey, consumerSecret, oAuthToken, oAuthTokenSecret, requestType.ToString(), timeStamp, nonce, out normalizedUrl, out normalizedRequestParameters);

        var request = new RestRequest(relativeUri);
        request.Resource = string.Format(relativeUri);
        request.Method = Method.GET;
        request.AddParameter("oauth_consumer_key", consumerKey);
        request.AddParameter("oauth_token", oAuthToken);
        request.AddParameter("oauth_nonce", nonce);
        request.AddParameter("oauth_timestamp", timeStamp);
        request.AddParameter("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1");
        request.AddParameter("oauth_version", "1.0");
        request.AddParameter("oauth_signature", sig);

        return request;
    }
```

I tried many things with RestClient and C#, nothing worked. What am I missing, in order to match the working Postman request. HTTP GET is working for me in RestSharp, only HTTP Post is not working.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know what "not working" means. You should eliminate that from your vocabulary. Instead, describe exactly what is wrong. Do you get an exception? What error message does the server return? How does it not work as you expect it to?

Comment: The request is failing with Status 'Forbidden', and Content says 'oauth_problem=signature_invalid...'

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I finally got my working, went the same wrong way trying to implement signature creation myself.. as I badly interpreted PostMan RestSharp code.
This could be done much easier as RestSharp does it all for you! I wish this was the version PostMan gave as a "code" example. Anyway, this works for me in C# (quick console app):

```
const string consumer_key = "abcd1234";
const string consumer_secret = "1234abcd";
const string access_token = "1a2b3c4d";
const string token_secret = "a12b3c4d";
const string URL = "https://aa.web.site.net/history/api/account/123456789/givemedata/search?offset=0&limit=50";

static void Main(string[] args)
{
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var client = new RestClient(URL);
client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForAccessToken(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, token_secret, RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1);
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(URL, Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"start\": {\"from\": 1583074556000, \"to\": 1588258556000 } }", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Yes, I know, no headers, no param sorting and hashing.. no nonce-nse :)

Answer (score 2):

thanks Pete, this code saves me hours of try and error!
the only code I added here is `Realm`

```
OAuth1Authenticator lAuthenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForAccessToken(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, token_secret, RestSharp.Authenticators.OAuth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha256);
lAuthenticator.Realm = "my_Realm";
client.Authenticator = lAuthenticator;
```