# Converting Postman Body form-data parameters to RestSharp C# POST request

Tags: c#, api, postman, restsharp

Would anyone know how to convert the below Postman POST Body form-data parameters to RestSharp C# POST request, nothing I have tries worked for me so far. The end  point is using OAuth 1.0, and I can post succesfully only with Body form-data, no other Body options do the trick.

[image]

The postman RestSharp translated to:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shipping/templates");
        var request2 = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request2.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request2.AddHeader("authorization", "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=" + consumerKey + ",oauth_token=" + oAuthToken + ",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\",oauth_timestamp="+ timeStamp + ",oauth_nonce=" + nonce +",oauth_version=\"1.0\",oauth_signature=" + sig + "");
        request2.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
        request2.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\ntest title\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"origin_country_id\"\r\n\r\n209\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"primary_cost\"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"secondary_cost\"\r\n\r\n1\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response2 = client.Execute(request2);
```

But this does not work with RestSharp, it throws StatusCode Forbidden, and Content 'oauth_problem=signature_invalid...'

How to make it work? The parameters can be only passed in with Body form-data

Update: Code used for generating nonce, timestamp, signature, etc:

```
            OAuthBase oAuth = new OAuthBase();

        string nonce = oAuth.GenerateNonce();
        string timeStamp = oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp();
        string normalizedUrl;
        string normalizedRequestParameters;

        string relativeUri = "url";
        string sig = oAuth.GenerateSignature(new Uri(BASE_URL.ToString() + relativeUri), consumerKey, consumerSecret, oAuthToken, oAuthTokenSecret, RequestType.POST.ToString(), timeStamp, nonce, out normalizedUrl, out normalizedRequestParameters);
```

Comment: Show the code where you set the consumerkey,oauthtoken,nonce etc.

Comment: I don't know about C#, but just curious: did you use Postman's Code Generator to generate this code?

Comment: yes, This is the exact code generated by Postman for c# RestSharp

Comment: The code for setting up the nonce, timestamp, etc is generated correctly, it is the same method I have used when generating these for my HTTP GET calls, and HTTP GET works just fine, HTTP POST is the only one failing. It is got to be related to how I post the data

Comment: So, were you able to found out the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RestSharp C# HTTP POST Oauth 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53975263/restsharp-c-sharp-http-post-oauth-1)