# OAuth 1.0 default request token URL in Postman, how to obtain?

Tags: c#, oauth, postman

Maybe title is not that clear but..

I have created a POST query that works in Postman using OAuth 1.0 authentication.
Mu calls are made to url:
https://lo.enghist.liveperson.net/abc/api/def/1234567/ghi/search

How does postman know all other urls - to request token url etc.
I’m trying to rewrite it in a custom C# app but have no idea how to track what happens when I click send - if I go to Developer Console I only see the final request with final params that were obtained somewhere?
Is it always sth default like:
https://lo.enghist.liveperson.net/oauth/request_token

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself:

1. I didn't correctly understand OAuth 1.0. I first thought that there is a different URL that we make calls to receive the token which we then use to make the final call. This is not the case, we create our token using secrets, nonce (random string) and few other rules, then it's all hashed and sent to WebService which does the same and compares both values.
2. Postman now provides you with code - below the button "Send" there is a link "Code" which gives you so many languages and one of them is C# using RestSharp.
3. Regarding above, it sadly shows a semi working solution - quite a lot of logic is skipped and all the values are precalculated so I was thinking I need to calculate them myself even if RestSharp can do that for you, please check my final working code here:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/64819771/1619684